docopt.DocoptLanguageError: "usage:" (case-insensitive) not found
It doesn't matter what do I do it keep sending my this error

from docopt import docopt
from api import *
from tabulate import tabulate
usage='''app
        this script is disigned for managing money
            usage :
                app.py -h
                app.py --init     
                app.py --add <item> <pay> [<information>]
                app.py --show [<item>]       
'''



opt = docopt(usage)

I tried other advises in this website and others as well but nun of them worked

Please note that the docopt project appears to have been abandoned, as there have not been any releases for over 10 years. Also, Python 3.3 appears to be the last supported version.  Perhaps use the builtin argparse library instead.

Thanks for your help
